# Two matrix with different determinant - does it surely says they are not similar?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have two matrices [image]

I would like to know if having a different determinant surely says that they aren't similar.

Thanks.

Comment: How do you define similar matrices?  It should be $A$ and $B$ are similar if there exists an invertible matrix $S$ such that $A=SBS^{-1}$.  Now... look at the determinant of both sides.  $\det(A)=\det(SBS^{-1})=\det(S)\det(B)\det(S^{-1})=\dots$.  Continuing we learn:  If $A$ and $B$ are similar then _______.   We further learn the contrapositive statement  If ______ then $A$ and $B$ are not similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A$ and $B=P^{-1}AP$ be similar matrices. Since the determinant
is multiplicative,
$$
\det(B)=\det(P^{-1}AP)=\det(P^{-1})\det(A)\det(P)=\det(A)\det(P^{-1})\det(P)=\det(AP^{-1}P)=\det(A).
$$
What does this tell you about two matrices that do not have the same
determinant?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  $A$ and $B$ are similar if and only if there is some invertible matrix $P$ such that $A = PBP^{-1}$.  What's the determinant of the right-hand side?

Comment: Hint of the hint: $det(AB)=det(A)det(B)$.

Comment: @Koto, right, but I was trying not to give too much away here..  I guess it doesn't matter since there's a comment elsewhere that spells it out more.